# Solve $y'-xy =x^3y^2$ with $z(x)$ substitution to separable equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

The Bernoulli equation:

$$y' + g(x)y = h(x)y^a$$

can be made into a separable equation with the variable substitution

$$z(x) = y(x)e^G(x)$$

where

$$G(x) = \int g(x)$$

**A)** Determine this separable equation.

**B)** Use this kind of substitution to solve the differential equation:

$$y'-xy =x^3y^2$$

**Attempted solution:**

**A)**

This is relatively straightforward. Using the substitution gives:

$$z(x) = y(x)e^G(x) \Rightarrow y(x) = \frac{z(x)}{e^G(x)} = z(x)e^{-G(x)}$$

Taking the derivative with the product rule:

$$y'(x) = z(x) \cdot -G'(x)e^{-G(x)} + z'(x) \cdot e^{-G(x)} = -z(x)g(x)e^{-G(x)} + z'(x)e^{-G(x)}$$

Putting it into the original equation gives:

$$-z(x)g(x)e^{-G(x)} + z'(x)e^{-G(x)} + g(x)z(x)e^{-G(x)} = z(x)^a e^{-aG(x)}h(x)$$

Simplifying:

$$z'(x)e^{-G(x)} = z(x)^a e^{-aG(x)}h(x)$$

Gathering the z:s to one side (omitting some notation):

$$\frac{z'}{z} = h(x)e^{(1-a)G(x)}$$

This is the expected answer.

**B)**

The equation to solve is:

$$y'-xy =x^3y^2$$

Using the result of **A)** gives us:

$$\frac{z'}{z} = x^3e^{(1-2)*-x^2/2} = x^3e^{x^2/2}$$

Integrating both sides gives:

$$\ln z = e^{x^2/2}(x^2-2) +C$$

Going back to $y$ gives:

$$\ln (ye^{x^2/2}) = e^{x^2/2}(x^2-2) +C \Rightarrow \ln y + \frac{x^2}{2} = e^{x^2/2}(x^2-2) + C$$

I am stuck here since I do not seem to be able to get to the expected answer of:

$$y = \frac{e^{x^2/2}}{C-(x^2-2)e^{x^2/2}}$$
$$y = 0$$

Here I will assume that I can infer the trivial solution of $y = 0$ by inspecting the original equation.

Comment: you have a sign mistake ( it dosent change that much though) $\ln (ye^{\color{red}{-x^2/2}}) = e^{x^2/2}(x^2-2) +C \Rightarrow \ln y + \frac{x^2}{2} = e^{x^2/2}(x^2-2) + C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G(x)=\int g(x)=\int -xdx=-\frac 12 x^2$$
$$\implies z(x)=ye^{-x^2/2}$$
We have that:
$$z'=y'e^{-x^2/2}-xye^{-x^2/2}=e^{-x^2/2}(y'-xy)$$
$$y'-xy =x^3y^2$$
$$z'e^{x^2/2}=x^3z^2(e^{x^2/2})^2$$
$$z'=x^3z^2(e^{x^2/2})$$
$$(-\frac 1 z)'=x^3(e^{x^2/2})$$
Integrate:
$$(-\frac 1 z)=\int x^3(e^{x^2/2})dx$$
$$(-\frac 1 z)=e^{x^2/2}( x^2-1)+C$$
$$-\frac 1 ye^{x^2/2}=e^{x^2/2}( x^2-1)+C$$
$$-\frac y {e^{x^2/2}}=\frac 1 {e^{x^2/2}( x^2-1)+C}$$
$$y(x) =-\frac {e^{x^2/2}} {e^{x^2/2}( x^2-1)+C}$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=\frac {e^{x^2/2}} {K-e^{x^2/2}( x^2-1)}}$$
Are you sure the formula you get in question A is correct ? The foollowing one seems more correct to me: 
$$\frac{z'}{\color {red}{z^\alpha}} = h(x)e^{(1-a)G(x)}$$
And if you apply that formula for this case you get
$$\frac{z'}{\color {red}{z^2}} = x^3e^{x^2/2}$$
Yes I checked your formula you forgot the exponent $\alpha$. It's $z^\alpha$ at the denominator. And you have some sign mistakes also as I pointed in the comment.